# Vector function of scalar argument

Tags: vectors

Prove that when $\vec{r} = \vec{a}e^{\omega t} + \vec{b}e^{-\omega t},$ where 
$\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ - const vector, then $\vec{\ddot{r(t)}} - \omega^{2}\vec{r} = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be straightforward that $$\dot{\vec{r}}=\omega \vec{a}e^{\omega t}-\omega \vec{b}e^{-\omega t}$$ and $$\ddot{\vec{r}}=\omega^2 \vec{a}e^{\omega t}+\omega ^2 \vec{b}e^{-\omega t}=\omega ^2 \vec{r}$$